# How to update material of cube on runtime using WebGL?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using three.js for doing animations. I want to dynamically update a material of a cube mesh. Here is example:

```
// create cube geometry 
var material1 = [new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xBEE2FF}),.....];
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(50, 50, 50,0,0,0,material1 );
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial());

// ...

var material2 = [new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xFFFFFF}), ...];
cube.geometry.materials = material2;
```

If I use CanvasRenderer, it works. But when I change to WebGL Renderer, it throws error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

How to update the material of a cube on runtime using WebGL?

Answer (score 4):

With a code fragment, it is difficult to know what is causing the error, but you cannot change materials that involve the presence or not of a texture. Try keeping all of your materials of the same type. Also, you may need to set `material.needsUpdate` flag to `true`.

You can find more detail and examples in the Three.js wiki about how to update things with `WebGLRenderer`.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Also, here is a fiddle that does something similar to what you appear to be trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/2FZU7/51/

EDIT: fiddle updated for three.js r.58

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you're setting 'materials' and not 'material' on your cube.

```
cube.material = material2;
material.map = texture;
material.needsUpdate = true;
```